# Near Field from a Dipole Antenna

Tags: electromagnetic, dipole, near-field

What are the equations defining the near field of a half-wave dipole antenna? What is the rate of decay of E-field and H-field in the near field (both reactive and radiative zones)? How are the equations different from those for an Infinitesimal Dipole?

[image: Infinitesimal Dipole E and H-field]

Comment: https://www.ahsystems.com/articles/primer%20on%20antenna%20near-field%20and%20far-field.php or, use Biot Savart law for the H field and equivalent for the E field.

Comment: @Andyaka are equations derived for infinitely small dipole applicable to half wave dipole...?

Comment: I have no idea.

Comment: I'm not sure the answer would be meaningful unless you were studying E&M up to the point where the book describes this -- and if you're at that point, the book gives the answer.  What do you get when you do an Internet search on "Near field from a Dipole Antenna"?

Comment: If I remember well, equations are for a "short" dipole only, nearest dipole (terms with 1/r^2, 1/r^3), ( l << lambda). There are the result of the integration of formulas for an infinitesimal dipole antenna.

Answer (score 1):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near_and_far_field

According to the three regions, one can plot how the fields vanish with distance ...

[image]